# C# / SQL Server - can't have two connections simultaneously to one database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

If I have SQL Server Management Studio open to my database, I can't open the database in my C# program because it will throw an error. I have to close the connection in Management Studio.

Is there a way to be able to connect to a single database with multiple connections?

This is just a local `.mdf` file on my computer that I'm working with.

Comment: Why don't you post the error message? Thanks.

Comment: "it will throw an error" is far too vague to help you. What is the error? And what sort of database connection is it?

Comment: is your SSMS connection perhaps in forced single-user mode? How exactly are you trying to connect? What is the connection string, for example? Heck, what type of SQL Server is it? Full? Express? CE? LocalDB?

Comment: The error message says "Cannot open user default database. Login failed."  I'm using sql express 2012 and my connection string is "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SomeAppDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you connect with a user instance, which is single-user only and normally used just for development:

> User instance scenarios include:
>
> - Any single-user application where sharing data is not required.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx

So your default SQL Server instance has the database open in your Management Studio session. When your program creates a new instance it can't access the database file because it is open with a different instance.

You can try using your server tool in Visual Studio to manage your database instead of Management Studio.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but are you sure about the one connection limitation? See this other Q&A: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31173/max-connections-sql-server-express-could-have

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you're right, this was apparently in older versions. The problem (I understand) is on the user-instance mode. Edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid connecting directly to the .mdf file.  Have SQL Server host the database, and then connect to it from there rather than the file.